# C: printing whole row in multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional array in C that goes like this:

```
int pop[18000][3] = {
  0, 1, 24,
  0, 2, 46,
  /* many other rows */
  6, 17999, 10,
  6, 18000, 10,
};
```

What I want to do is write a function that checks the last value of each row and, if it has a certain value, returns the whole row. I know that I can do it the messy way

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
  if (pop[i][1] == 10)
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", pop[i][0], pop[i][1], pop[i][2]);
```

But I am actually looking for a more general solution that allows me to print selected whole rows (as in, in certain simulations, I might end up creating 2-dimensional arrays with dozens if not hundreds of columns; I don't want to have to use the messy method for that).

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0;i<18000;i++)
{

 if(pop[i][2] == 10) // u sed last column
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
       printf("%d",pop[i][j]);
 }
```

Helpful?

Comment: I'm currently embarrassed to hell that this didn't occur to me :/

Answer (score 0):

use a helper function :

```
void printArray(int *array, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
       printf("%d", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

usage :

```
for (i = 0; i < ROWS_COUNT; i++)
  if (pop[i][COLUMNS_COUNT - 1] == 10)
     printArray(pop[i], COLUMNS_COUNT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would allocate a one-dimensional array of length `rows*columns` and use the following function:

```
void print(int *pop, int index, int value, int rows, int columns) {

    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        if(pop[i+(j-1)*index] ==  value) {
            for(j=0; j<columns; j++) {
                printf("%d, ", pop[i+j*columns]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When you call the function you simply pass the array as argument with the number of rows and columns it has and the column number `index` on which you want to check for the value `value`. In this way you can use the function for any two-dimensional array for an arbitrary column number and value

```
// ...

int rows = 18000;
int columns = 3;
int index = 3;
int value = 10;
int *pop = malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*columns);

// Fill your pop array here

print(pop, index, value, rows, columns);

// ...
```